# Navigate from Login/Signup ViewController to SWRevealViewController's sw_front ViewController using swift2

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift2, swrevealviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` to implement sidebar in my iOS app.I have followed [AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/) tutorial. what is happening right now is if i set `SWRevealViewController` as my initial View controller it works fine. But I need to navigate from Login or Signup ViewController to `SWRevealViewController's` sw_front page. I tried to set a push segue from Login/Signup ViewController to sw_front viewcontroller but i got an error saying

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is
>   managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'

How can i navigate from my Login/Signup viewcontroller to SWRevealviewcontroller's sw_front ViewController which contains my menu details ? Need help...

Answer (score 1):

> Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.

The above reason is your VC not in `Navigation Controller Stack`

**add Navigation Controller to your initial viewController**

1. Select the initial viewController
2. Go To **Editor**--> **Embed In** --> **Navigation Controller.**

Comment: i already have a navigation controller for my initial ViewController ie the login ViewController. need to do anything else ???

Comment: i am currently making changes to the sample project i got from AppCoda . if i can make it work then i can implement it in my project. Can i send that one ?

Comment: its ok what ever in your hand send to me

Comment: I tried setting a navigation controller to my initial Controller. and it worked. but another problem instead of showing a menu hamburger button i could see a **<Back** button

Comment: you dont need to push ,in here you need to use **Modal** Segue

Comment: what's the difference between this push and modal. i understand what is push  but not modal...

Comment: now it is working . but my question is when a user taps the sign in button we need some process to execute and then need to navigate to SWRevealViewController. how can i navigate to SWRevealViewController programatically ???

Comment: if you identify the stack use performsegue else use storyboard ID but both are need to show on transistion style as Modal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94069/discussion-between-joker-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: bro any help do u need

Comment: Ofcourse looking forward for any help from anyone... With your help i managed to achieve what  i was looking for. :)